# Error when installing chaincode - failed to calculate dependencies: incomplete package

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am try to installing Chaincode, follow the tutorial of hyperledger. But when I try to run the command

`peer chaincode install -p chaincodedev/chaincode/sacc -n mycc -v 0`

The terminal gives error message

> Error: error getting chaincode deployment spec for mycc: error getting chaincode package bytes: failed to calculate dependencies: incomplete package: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim

I see some other people got similar issue, but there is no answer yet. I am new to these stuffs, so any suggestions can be helpful.

Comment: share those link which you have tried and also provide the dependency file. I mean build.gradle or pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Fabric and samples you are using, but this looks like a change that was made for Fabric 2.0 and described in the [release notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v2.0.0) "The shim package and dependencies for go chaincode are no longer included in
the chaincode build environment."

There is more detail in the associated [Jira entry.](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5177)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to follow the tutorial for Fabric 2.0. So could you give me some advice about how to solve this issue? I understand this feature is gone, but I still don't know how to install Chaincode. I also noticed that you mentioned about dependency file, but I don't know where they are located. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it today:

After loging into CLI contaier execute the following command (import the shim package). This will import the package into cli container where the chaincode will be compiled.

go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim

then execute

peer chaincode install -p chaincodedev/chaincode/sacc -n mycc -v 0

It will work cheers.

Comment: After logging into "cli" container means after executing the following command: docker exec -it cli bash

Comment: after executing your suggestion i did get shim but still the same issue. Please help me further.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the shim package to the GOPATH

go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim

This downloads the shim package to /src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim inside your GOPATH . Then provide the path to this shim package inside import in your chaincode.

It should be like below:

import (
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim"
)

Comment: This one worked for me. I think after upgraded 2.2 the package was changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was incorrect path. CLI container work dir has already `chaincodedev` part of the path

```
cli:
    ...
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/chaincodedev
```

You can do following to validate if this is true in your case

```
docker exec -it cli bash
pwd
```

You have to see `/opt/gopath/src/chaincodedev`.

So all I needed to do is just remove `chaincodedev` from command path

```
peer chaincode install -p chaincode/sacc -n mycc -v 0
```